# AngularJS - Using service to update view when user goes offline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm building an app that needs to detect when a user loses internet connectivity or cannot reach the server.  Multiple controllers and services need to be able to check and set this.  I have achieved all of this with no problem using an angular service and

```
window.addEventListener('offline', function() {OfflineService.checkIfOnline});
```

then in the service with something like

```
window.navigator.onLine ? online = true : online = false
```

The tricky part comes in when I need to update the view when the offline event occurs.  I can't seem to find a way to update the scope property or a controller property when the service property gets updated by the event.

When I use $scope.$watch, the function fires 10 times (noted by console.log) and then never again.

I tried to replicate the problem in a jsfiddle, but this is my first time using that tool, and I'm not sure if I did it right:

https://jsfiddle.net/m3nx5yLm/1/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-idle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-idle) ?

Comment: The watch fires 10 times because that's the angular's digest. For any view-related update, you don't need to do any watch: just reference the value to the scope (or to the "this" of the controller) and you're done. As long as it's binded to the controller, the view automatically updates itself when it changes... Unless you bind the value using `::`. The relevant service, controller and html structure would be appreciated for further understanding anyway.

Comment: @briosheje I have also tried binding the value to a controller, but I cannot figure out how to update the controller property when the service property gets updated.  Did you see the fiddle for the relevant information you are asking for, or do I need to make the fiddle more detailed?

Comment: @SeanIvins the fiddle is empty. In any case, you should bind the property to the **service** itself, so that when an angular controller uses it it gets automatically updated. The best approach you could follow is to bind such service property to the `rootScope`, so that each scope can easily inherit it. Don't initialize a controller variable for each controller: try to share it from above, so that you won't need to worry about issues any further ;)

Comment: @briosheje Oops updated the fiddle with my changes https://jsfiddle.net/m3nx5yLm/1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/m3nx5yLm/2/ shows me trying to use $rootScope without looking at the docs first (doing that now).  Any insight after seeing the jsfiddle is appreciated.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/m3nx5yLm/3/

```
constructor($scope, OfflineNotificationService){
```

Looks like you were referencing the class from the scope not the instance created by the injector (needed to pass it in along with $scope).  I also used the watch syntax where the first arg is a function just to be clear about making that call, the string syntax is typically just used to reference properties on scope.  A few other notes you can just return the window.navigator.onLine and you can store the value on the service instance and reference it directly from the view, you can then call checkOnline periodically with a $timeout loop or listening for the online/offline events on the browser instead of using the watch to fire the function.

https://jsfiddle.net/m3nx5yLm/4/

Comment: I apologize for forgetting about this question.  Your answer is a better solution.  Even though I didn't use it myself, your jsfiddle clearly shows it works, and as noted in the comments to my answer, I might be causing a memory leak with my implementation.  Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your help.

I ended up going with a solution suggested by a buddy of mine.  Using `$rootScope.$emit('offlineEvent' true);` in the service and listening for it in the controller with `$rootScope.$on('offlineEvent' this.setControllerProperty);`.

Comment: To avoid memory leaks, AngularJS event listeners should be attached to the $scope on which they are used. If attached to $rootScope, they need to be destroyed when no longer needed. For more information, see [AngularJS $rootScope/$scope API Reference - $destroy event](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#event-$destroy).

Comment: Also it is better to use `$rootScope.$broadcast`. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Event Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation).

Comment: Curious if you tried my answer or why you think it's worse than broadcasting events around?  Personally think events in angular should only be used for system wide things like route change success or things where an event might be used as a way to decouple multiple parent/child directives while still giving them a means of communicating.